# CharsetEncoder - Unmappable character replacement

Tags: java, character-encoding

*CharsetEncoder takes a sequences of characters, and encodes it, turning it into a sequence of bytes.*

I'm working on creating a Charset for use in Java, and I'm having a little trouble understanding the intent of the following.

From java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder's documentation:

> The possible error actions are to ignore the erroneous input, report the error to the invoker via the returned CoderResult object, or replace the erroneous input with the current value of the replacement byte array.

What I'm wondering is, does the replacement byte array replace a sequence of erroneous characters, or do you add a copy for every erroneous character?

For example, imagine the sequence of chars was `{'a', 'a', 'a'}` and your replacement byte sequence was `{0, 1}`. If you're working in a charset in which `'a'` is an illegal character, would you write `{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}`, replacing all illegal characters separately, or just `{0, 1}`, replacing the sequence of illegal characters?

*I know those aren't actually byte literals, but ints. Please just go with it. I figured that adding a ton of casts would simply make it harder to follow.*

I'm tempted to do it by character, but at the same time, it just feels weird to replace one character with a (potentially, though probably not) very long sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got back around to this, so I decided to test it. I wrote some code to test it, which, seen below, sans imports.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CharacterCodingException {
        CharBuffer chars = CharBuffer.wrap(new char[] {'ÿ', 'ÿ', 'ÿ'});
        CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder();
        encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
        ByteBuffer bytes = encoder.encode(chars);
        bytes.position(0);
        while(bytes.hasRemaining()) {
            System.out.print(bytes.get() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

And running it, I got the output:

> 63 63 63

So, three consecutive unmappable characters leads to three copies of the replacement byte array. Typically, the default replacement is the equivalent of a question mark (which is where the 63s came from).

In short, each unmappable character is replaced individually.